# Cocoa Objective C, getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in creating an array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa

I'm creating an array like so:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithString:@"testString"];
int id1 = 4;
NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:str, id1, @"TEST TEST TEST", nil];
```

But at runtime its coming up with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" but theres no variable that isn't being declared :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make id1 a NSNumber.

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:id1];
```

Answer (score 6):

NSArray can only hold objects, and id1 is not an object. Use NSNumber to wrap it in an object that you can store in your array:

```
NSNumber *id1Obj = [NSNumber numberWithInt:id1];
```

Answer (score 5):

`id1` is not an `NSObject`, it's a basic type. You can only add NSObject-derived objects to an NSArray.

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS is probably because, under the covers, it's trying to access an object stored at wherever your int is pointing to. In other words, it's using your int as a pointer to an NSObject and failing horribly when it does so.